# How to calculate the resolution of a GC-FID peak using only peak area and height

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I think the title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to calculate the resolution of my GC-FID peaks, but the software doesn't report the width of the peaks. Do I need to manually do this by approximating the peak width or should I treat each peak like a triangle and back-calculate from the height and area? I realize the second option is most likely not correct though.

Thanks

Comment: "A pure Gaussian peak with a peak height h and full-width at half-maximum w has a total area of 1.064467*h*w." [Source](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/Integration.html)

Comment: There is no commercial GC-FID software which will not give peak widths. What is the instrument and what software are you using?